# Pronouns : One's / their

Tags: pronouns, exam-questions, singular-they

When do we use One's / their ?

> One must keep one's promise.
>   I know this is correct as it is a well known phrase / quote.

But what about this sentence ?

> One should exercise **their** right to vote.

Will we use *one's* here too ?

Is it that if subject is *One* then the pronoun will be always *one's* or it can be *their* too ?

Comment: In BrE the pronoun "one" is always used with "one's" and "oneself"/"one's self".  In AmE there is a tradition of using "one" with "his", and hence (presumably) "their".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In colloquial English, we have a habit of using [singular they](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they). Grammatically, it's not advised (due to modern English using "you"), but it's become the norm to use "they" as a subject for any singular subject.

You can use either **one** or **their** in your example above.

> One should exercise **one's** right to vote.

works just as well as

> One should exercise **their** right to vote.

The former is more proper and is grammatically correct. **One's** always works as a possessive form for **one**.  The latter is understood in spoken English, and is generally more widely used.

Comment: While I find singular *they* distracting, and take pains to avoid it, that's not the same as calling it incorrect. It's arguably no more incorrect than plural *you* — *ye* is the proper plural second person pronoun.

Comment: @choster Thanks! I suppose you're right. I revised my answer. :)

Comment: Just to note, it's actually the singular `you` that was (once) grammatically incorrect.  `Ye` was the plural subject pronoun, and `you` was the plural object pronoun.  The corresponding singular pronouns were `thou` and `thee`.

Comment: @PMV That's true. I did note in my answer that I was referring to modern English, which I supposed meant that, colloquially, we no longer use archaic terms like "ye" and "thou" and "thee" (except in specific circumstances, of course). It's become proper to use "you" for both singular and plural, but it's a good historical distinction to point out the word's former singular-only usage. :)